# Cannot break out of an infinite loop in c++

Tags: c++

So I first wrote a script in python to test if what I am trying to do works because I am familiar with it(and it does). It prints 1 to 10 every loop and continues doing it.

```
fullCircle = 2*3.14159
numberOfPoints = 10

def gen():
    angle = 0
    points  = []
    while angle < fullCircle:
        angle += (1 / numberOfPoints) * fullCircle
        points.append(angle)
        print(len(points))


while True:
    gen()
```

Then I tried writing the exact same code in c++, but for some reason the loop does not break and the angle continues increasing even after `angle < fullCircle`  and I cant figure out why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

float fullCircle =  2 * 3.14159f;
int numberOfPoints = 10;
std::vector<float> points;

void gen()
{
    float angle = 0;
    points.clear();

    while (angle < fullCircle)
    {
        angle += (1 / numberOfPoints) * fullCircle;
        points.push_back(angle);
        std::cout << points.size() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    while (true)
        gen();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this statement:

`angle += (1 / numberOfPoints) * fullCircle;`

`numberOfPoints` is an `int` set to `10`, so `(1 / numberOfPoints)` is **integer division**.  In normal arithmetic, `(1 / 10)` is `0.1`, but an integer can't have a decimal, so the result of `(1 / 10)` in this case is an **integer** value of `0`, thus `0 * fullCircle` results in `0`, and so `angle` does not change value.

If one of the operands of the `/` operator is updated to `float` or `double`  then **floating-point division** will be used instead, resulting in a **floating-point** value of `0.1`, thus `0.1 * fullCircle` will not result in `0`, and so `angle` will change value.

The simplest change is this:

```cpp
float numberOfPoints = 10; // or double
```

But one of these will work, too:

```cpp
int numberOfPoints = 10;
...
angle += (1 / float(numberOfPoints)) * fullCircle;
```

```cpp
int numberOfPoints = 10;
...
angle += (1.0f / numberOfPoints) * fullCircle;
```

Comment: But `angle` does change value. It increases but its not float and that's the problem I think. But yea, your solution works. Thanks

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes "*But angle does change value*" - not in the original code shown, since the statement evaluates as effectively `angle += 0;` You can prove that by printing out the new value of `angle` on each loop iteration.

Comment: @Ahh, I just clocked what you mean. I understand it now

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
angle += (1 / numberOfPoints) * fullCircle;
```

never changes the value of angle.  (1 / numberOfPoints) is always zero as numberOfPoints is of type int.

Changing the line to

```
angle += (1.0f / numberOfPoints) * fullCircle;
```

would fix it.